# ReactJS onChange inputfield while typing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to execute a additional function in ReactJS onChange in input type text field, then render function is:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <InputText />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The InputText component is:

```
class InputText extends React.Component {

    onChange(e){
        console.log("you typed again...");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" placeholder="search..." onChange={this.onChange()} />
        );
    }
}
```

The console log is to execute while user is typing but with my method the console log comes only if page is loaded.

What I have to fix there to get it runing if user start with typing?

Comment: `onChange={this.onChange}`, without `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the function within the `onChange` prop, like:

```
onChange={this.onChange()}
```

you only need to pass the function, like:

```
onChange={this.onChange}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `()` from `this.onChange()`. That's all.